# SugarCrm REST Access using RestSharp

Tags: rest, sugarcrm, restsharp

I am trying to Login or SugarCrm using REST. I have this code,,

```
        //Login
        var data = new JObject();
        data["user_name"] = "admin";
        data["password"] = @"xxx";

        var client = new RestClient(@"http://ubuntu-server");

        var request = new RestRequest(@"service/v2/rest.php", Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("method", "login");
        request.AddParameter("input_type", "json");
        request.AddParameter("response_type", "json");
        request.AddParameter("rest_data", data);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

The response I get is "Invalid Login"

What are I doing wrong??

//lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that stick out:

1. The password needs to be MD5 encoded
2. The data object needs to be wrapped in an addition 'user_auth' object.